# Magento 1.9 - Pass value From Select into Gallery.phtml to uploadAction into GalleryController.php

Tags: product, adminhtml, image, upload, gallery

I need check the value set into custom select during Upload Image

Manage Product -> Product -> Image -> User Browse image

into Gallery.phtml

example i add this simple select

```
<select id="type">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

after user Click Upload

During Upload, into uploadAction

Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController

i need check what is the value set into my custom select

what should I do?

Other info:
I've already created a personal admin template, and overridden the class and everything works,
I just have to know how to retrieve the value